# test image src against ad blocker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, adblock

I have a long list of image urls in my db.
Some of them ad-block detect the img's src as commercial and remove them.

I am looking for easy way to get the problematic images against [ad-block regex list](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt).

I've tried to a script to get all images to an html page, and hoped to run on chrome with adblock but got errors (Firefox as well) as they are too many.

My app build using Ruby on Rails.

Comment: I don't think those are regex patterns

Comment: If you think the problem with your methodology is "too many images", why don't you simply write out multiple HTML pages?

Comment: @GolfWolf I understood it from here : https://adblockplus.org/en/subscriptions , I know it is not all regex, consider it as list of rules.

Comment: @JLB I will need to scan multiple HTML pages manually to find errors. That will be too many.